# Get ID of newly inserted record in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using detailsview to insert records into database, I would like a confirmation to appear after insert that displays the ID of the new record.  I am using the following code:

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserted(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemInserted


    Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("houses").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"

    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim obj As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Response.Write("<div class=newlisting> The Record ")
        Response.Write("<span class=deletedlistinghighlight>")
        Response.Write(obj.ToString)
        Response.Write("</span> Was Added.</div>")


    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

The confirmation appears at the top of the page but it will not show the ID and I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Where is your insert statement ?

Comment: I am using the insert that is auto generated with the sqldatasource

Comment: I changed "SELECT @@IDENTITY" to "SELECT MAX(ID)" and it worked

Comment: That will work as long as no other job is inserting data concurrently. In that case, you might get back the value of that insert.

Comment: You don't have to do it in this way.  
Rather than calling one more sub after insertion, just use OUT parameter in your Insert procedure and you will get your newly added ID back right after the new row is inserted.